# Send a child of the target to a function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a set up like this:

```
<a href="#"><span class="pickme"></span></a>
<a href="#"><span class="pickme"></span></a>
<a href="#"><span class="pickme"></span></a>
```

How can I trigger the `mouseenter` on the parent but have the function `enterBtn(e.target)` pass along the child `.pickme`?

```
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    enterBtn(e.target);
  });
  $(this).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    leaveBtn(e.target);
  });
});
```

Comment: You can use `.find()` i.e. `enterBtn($(this).find('.pickme').get(0))`

Comment: @Satpal Thanks that is what I needed. Add as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)/[`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) to target the child. As you function accepts a DOM element, use [`.get(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the refrernece of it.

```
$('a').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    enterBtn($(this).find('.pickme').get(0));
}).on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    leaveBtn($(this).find('.pickme').get(0));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()` to find the `.pickme` child :

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.pickme').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    enterBtn(e.target);
  });
  $(this).find('.pickme').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    leaveBtn(e.target);
  });
});
function enterBtn(e) { console.log($(e).text() + ' In'); }
function leaveBtn(e) { console.log($(e).text() + ' Out'); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#"><span class="pickme">A</span></a>
<a href="#"><span class="pickme">B</span></a>
<a href="#"><span class="pickme">C</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use children() method from the jquery api it will select the child element of the selector parent use the class name as a parameter for this method to include only child with that class if you don't pass any parameters it will.select all child.

```
$('a').each(function() {
$(this).on('mouseenter', function() {
enterBtn($(this).children(".pikckme"));
});
 $(this).on('mouseleave', function() {
 leaveBtn($(this).children(".pickme"));
});
});
```